# Determine the volume of the cuboid in cubic centimeters.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

**When the length of a cuboid increases by $1cm$, the volume will be increased by $12cm^3$ . When the width increases by $2cm$, the volume will be increased by $15cm^3$. When the height increases by $3cm$, the volume will increased by $30cm^3$. Determine the volume of the cuboid in cubic centimeters.**

My solutions: 
$1.$ -> $ x^3 + x^2 = x^3 + 12$ -> $x = \sqrt{12}$ 
$2.$ -> $ x^3 + 2x^2 = x^3 + 15$ -> $x = \sqrt{7.5}$ 
$3.$ -> $ x^3 + 3x^2 = x^3 + 30$ -> $x = \sqrt{10}$ 
And I didn’t even try to cube them because
I’m guessing my solutions are wrong, like the $x$’s are different? I am just confused and I’d be happy if anyone would helped me.

Comment: I would start by assuming that the length is $L$, width is $W$ and height is $H$. Now the initial volume is $V=LWH$. Also, your solution falls apart immediately when one asks "What is $x$?" ... It's always a good idea to approach your own solutions like this, by asking such questions.

Comment: A cuboid is not the same thing as a cube.

Comment: Ohhh I’m sorry I completely thought a cuboid is thee same thing as a cube, thank you for pointing that out @JaapScherphuis.

Comment: Thanks you for the advise @MattiP. !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the dimensions be $l,w,h$. Turning words into maths, you get $3$ equations:

$$(l+1)wh =lwh +12 \\ l(w+2)h = lwh +15 \\ lw(h+3) =lwh +30 $$ which simplify to $$ wh=12 \\ lh =7.5 \\ lw =10 $$ Multiplying these gives $$ (lwh)^2 = 900 $$ Thus, the volume is $$lwh =30$$

Comment: I completely understand now, thank you for the simple explanation!